# Int object is not callable error when trying to output two values

Tags: python

I am trying to create a program to give the length and width of a rectangle given the perimeter and diagonal. I have two formulas, one for l and one for w. The only difference is the initial minus/plus, for the quadratic formula.

I have tried re-writing the formula to make sure there are no syntax errors but that does not work.

```
from math import sqrt as s
def sum_area(p, d):
    l = (p/4) + (s((p/2)**2-(4((p/2)**2-d**2)/2))/2) 
    w = (p/4) - (s((p/2)**2-(4((p/2)**2-d**2)/2))/2) 
    return [l,w]
print(sum_area(28,10))
```

The program should output [6,8]. I have tested this using pen and paper.

Comment: `4((p/2)**2-d**2)` evaluates to `4()`, you need proper symbols for multiplication, it thinks you're trying to call a method on the number `4`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You typed 4( which is wrong, you want 4*( I am guessing.

```
from math import sqrt as s
def sum_area(p, d):
    l = (p/4) + (s((p/2)**2-(4*((p/2)**2-d**2)/2))/2) 
    w = (p/4) - (s((p/2)**2-(4*((p/2)**2-d**2)/2))/2) 
    return [l,w]
print(sum_area(28,10))
```